# Python modify the parent instance method by the child class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a class ParentA, ChildB, and ChildC. The relationship is shown in the figure. How can I overwrite the run() function in the ParentA through ChildC?
[image]

```
class ParentA:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        print("ParentA")

    def other(self):
        pass

class ChildB(ParentA):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def play(self):
        pass


class ChildC(ChildB):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

# The new run function is imported from other file
def run(a=1, b=2):
    print("new method")
    # Do a lot of new things...


child_b = ChildB()
child_c = ChildC()
print(child_b.run())
print(child_c.run())
```

I want to implement a function similar to:

```
replace(ChildC.run(), run())
```

The outputs are：

```
new method
new method
```

Comment: The indenting is suspicious here. Is the last `def run():` supposed to be a method of `ChildC`? If you want `ChildC` to have it's own `run()` method, just give it the method.

Comment: Thanks. The last run() function is imported from another file, and I added a comment

Comment: The question has nothing to do with inheritance. If the goal is simply to take an existing function, and modify the class so that it uses that function as a method - then yes, you can do that, and it doesn't matter what the base classes are. However, the function must take into account a `self` parameter. Please see the linked duplicate, and see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do it. `ParentA.run = run`

Answer (score 0):

If you want `ChildC` to have a run method that has a different implementation than `Parent.run`, override the method in `ChildC` like so:

```
class Parent:
    def run(self):
        print('Run from Parent')

class ChildA(Parent):
    pass

class ChildB(ChildA):
    def run(self):
        super().run()
        print('Run from ChildB')


c = ChildB()
c.run()
```

For the sake of the example, I call `super().run()` from `ChildB.run` but if you do not want `Parent.run` to execute, just omit that line.

Comment: It's not clear this is what they are asking. They have a `run` function that takes no arguments. It seem like they would like to make this *existing* function a method of `ChildC`. But it's not really clear.

Comment: @Mark that's a fair point and I agree. Updated the answer to put a disclaimer at the top and will update if I notice any response to your comment in the question.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I needed. Because my run() function has a lot of arguments. I also have some other ChildXXX inherited from ChildB. ChildB is used by another process, and I almost can't change it.

Comment: "Because my run() function has a lot of arguments." Why does this cause a problem? "I also have some other ChildXXX inherited from ChildB." Why does this cause a problem? Either they should have the same `run` method (in which case, add it to `ChildB` instead, so that it will be inherited), or else they shouldn't (in which case, it doesn't matter what changes you make to `ChildC`, the other `ChildXXX` will not be affected).

Answer (score 0):

do you mean redefine a method `run()` in child Class to overwrite the parent class's method?

```py
class ParentA:
    def run(self):
        print("ParentA")

class ChildB(ParentA):
    def run(self):
        print("ClassB")
```